# Qt/c++ call for a second window

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating a desktop application in qt using c++ and am struggling with linking two projects together. The first project is a chess game and the second one is from where i want to start . I want to add a new QPushbutton "Play a game" then a new window will open showing the game . I added all .cpp and .h file from the first projet to the main one and i don't know how can i call it the second window . I could've done it if it had a .ui file with just setmodel but  i can't because it doesn't have one. I don't know If i am making any sense right now but i'll provide you with screenshots just so you get me more.
The first project (the game): https://github.com/subeshb1/Chess
My project:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcC2l.png)

the game :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8JZe.png)

Comment: include appropriate header for the widget or dialpg you want, construct widget or dialog using new, make it display using thr appropriate call.  .ui files only generate headers and .cpp files.  If you have the .cpp and .h already then you can skip the .ui

Comment: Hi Sir i don't think you understand the issue . i already have the .h and .cpp files in my project and i can't call .ui file because there is no model it's all written in c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need .ui files.  You just have to write the function yourself.  I don't know what the main widget that owns the button is called so I'll call it TLWidget for now. and use ... to represent some other code that may be in there.

```
#include<QtWidgets/QDialog>
#include "game.h" // this is the widget you want in a new window

class TLWidget ... //this is the class definition of your top level widget.  it usually owns the thing created from the .ui
{
...
QDialog* m_ChessWindow; //a member is needed to hold or own the window
Game* m_ChessWidget; //the game itself
...
TLWidget (...) //this is the constructor (where the ui item is created or initialized)
{
...
//by making in the constructor, there's only one and it is easy to track.
//you can alternatively spawn a new window per button push by following the 3 calls here: the two new calls below with appropriate parents, and the show() call further below.
m_ChessWindow = new QDialog(this);
m_ChessWidget = new Game(m_ChessWindow);
...
}
...
void SpawnChess() //function that creates your widget.  You may want to put other steps in here or slot this, or call it from your button slot function
{
...
m_ChessWindow->show();//this will show the dialog
...
}
...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried that and i did some other steps too . Here's where am at right now.

1. Mainwindow.h

   #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
   #define MAINWINDOW_H
   #include "joueur.h"
   #include "partie.h"
   #include "game.h"

   #include

   QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
   namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
   QT_END_NAMESPACE

   class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
   {
   Q_OBJECT

   public:
   MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
   ~MainWindow();

   private slots:
   void on_ajouter_joueur_clicked();

   ```
   void on_lancer_partie_clicked();
   ..etc
   ```

   private:
   Ui::MainWindow *ui;
   Joueur J;
   Partie P;
   **Game *game;**

   };
   #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
2. Mainwindow.cpp

   void MainWindow::on_lancer_partie_clicked()
   {

   ```
   game = new Game();
   game->show();
   game->displayMainMenu();
   ```

   }
3. Main.cpp

   #include "mainwindow.h"
   #include 
   #include 
   #include 
   #include "game.h"

   **Game *game;**

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
   QApplication a(argc, argv);

   a.setStyle("fusion");
   MainWindow w;

   **game = new Game();**

   w.show();

   return a.exec();
   }

At this point , a new window pops when i click on the button but the chessboard and the chess pieces are nowhere to be found ! BTW i have all the files and ressources with the right path !
If i do this tho :

- Main.cpp

  #include "mainwindow.h"
  #include 
  #include 
  #include 
  #include "game.h"

  **Game *game;**

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
  QApplication a(argc, argv);

  a.setStyle("fusion");
  MainWindow w;

  **game = new Game();
  game->show();
  game->displayMainMenu();**

  w.show();

  return a.exec();

This way it works pretty fine not missing a single piece . So i figured it has something to do with the QApplication but i don't know how to use QApplication in mainwindow.cpp